# Orchard CMS Duplicate Content Error

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

We have a web site built with Orchard CMS v1.8.  We have had a couple of instances where the person that manages content has not been able to save changes to a Page.  They receive the following error.

> An unhandled exception has occurred and the request was terminated. Please refresh the page. If the error persists, go back
>   Sequence contains more than one matching element
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.BuildNewVersion(ContentItem existingContentItem) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:line 450 at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.Get(Int32 id, VersionOptions options, QueryHints hints) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:line 234 at Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers.AdminController.EditPOST(Int32 id, String returnUrl, Action`1 conditionallyPublish) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Contents\Controllers\AdminController.cs:line 308 at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41()

What can I do to elimiate the extra record(s) returned in the SingleOrDefault() call?  I don't know the database structure behind Orchard enough to find the "content records" but if I was able to find them I could delete the extra record(s).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause for this error that you have more than one version of the same content item with value `Latest = 1` (orchard use this value to determine the latest version for content item), to solve it you can run the following query to find the duplicate versions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord
WHERE ContentItemRecord_id = @Id
```

then be sure that there is only one record with value `Latest = 1`, `published = 1`, and `Number` is in sequence without duplicates.

FYI, in query use value `Id` for content item which has the error.

Comment: Do you have any idea how it gets into this state?  I don't know if the web site managers are doing something or if there is a bug in Orchard.

Comment: Mostly it's a bug, when more than one person save the same draftable content item at same time, in most cases orchard will handle it correctly, but in little cases will not, hope this will help you more.